# ClassNotFoundException for stub while activating a remote object

Tags: java, rmi, classnotfoundexception

```
 public void Test {
    String location = xyz; //location of the class file for the stub
    ActivationDesc desc = new ActivationDesc( "TestObjectImpl", location, null);
    ActivationID id = ActivationGroup.getSystem().registerObject(desc);
    TestObject to = (TestObject)id.activate(true);
 }
```

On running the above code, I get ClassNotFoundException for TestObjectImpl_stub . I looked around the web and found two possible workarounds:

1. Specify the path of the class files in CLASSPATH variable.
2. While executing the test, mention java.rmi.server.codebase=location along with the java command, location being the location of the class files.

Which of the above method is more appropriate? Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: They are both appropriate. I'm not much of a fan of the codebase feature just as a solution to this problem. It has its uses as part of a more general solution to class versioning and deployment, but it's a big bite to take just for this trivial purpose.

Comment: @EJP There is one more thing I dont understand..why do I need to set the location in the classpath when its already being sent in the  ActivationDesc() constructor?

Comment: The location needs to be a URL that is accessible by the activation daemon. Is it?

Comment: @EJP: Yes, the location is a URL. Its "the object's code location (the location of the class), a codebase URL path," from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/rmi/activation/ActivationDesc.html

Comment: You've ignored the last seven words of the question.

Comment: I don't know how it works internally. All i could find is that the descriptor object is registered with the activation  daemon. There is nothing about whether it should be accessible or not.

Comment: I didn't ask how it works internally. I asked whether the codebase URL is 'accessible by the activation daemon'. Posting the URL would be a good first step to getting that answered, if you don't already know the answer. For example, file:// URLs generally only work on the host they refer to.